# Having trouble importing Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to import flash except I keep on getting these errors :

[image]

I've already installed flash using "pip3 install flash" and Virtualenv using "pip install virtualenv"

Here's my code :

```
from flash import Flask, render_template, request

import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app_route('temperature', methods = ['POST'])
def temp():
    zip = request.form['zip']
    return zipcode
    return render_template("temperature.html")

@app_route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: use `flask` not `flash`, ie `from flask import Flask, render_template, request`

Comment: It's `pip3 install flask` with a `k`.

Answer (score 0):

Package you installed must be something else, not Flask: https://pypi.org/project/flash/

Install Flask with ‘pip3 install Flask’

And import ‘ from flask import Flask, render_template, request’